# Octave: error installing package on Windows

Tags: installation, octave

First of all, I know a lot of questions similar to mine have been asked, and nevertheless they don't help me solve the problem I'm facing. I'm running Octave 5.1.0.0 on Windows 10 Pro 64 bit. I'm having no issues but one: when I try to install Symbolic package by `pkg install symbolic-2.7.1.tar.gz` (downloaded from Octave Forge), I get the error

```
unpack: unarchiving program exited with status: 1
tar: Error opening archive: Failed to open 
'/C/Users/smlvcfncst/Downloads/symbolic-2.7.1.tar.gz'
error: called from
    unpack at line 274 column 5
    untar at line 48 column 5
    install at line 81 column 9
    pkg at line 441 column 9
```

and I have no clue where the problem related to the unpacking could be. Not only I have 7z and Winrar installed, but moreover I use a full installation of Cmder, so my system has everything that is needed to work with a .tar.gz

I've tried in different terminals, both with and without administrator privileges, and the problem persists. How should I proceed then?

*EDIT*: Following Andy's suggestion, I let you know that even before installing Octave I already have installed and used both Python and MinGW, as well as sympy module. Moreover, my Octave installation was the most standard possible for Windows, that is using the official .exe installer. No other package, apart from those included with installation, have been added before I tried adding symbolic.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: You really should start explaining exactly what you've did before you see the error. The octsympy package has a very detailed howto install Python, sympy and other dependencies

Comment: Please please please tell us exactly what you've did before you saw the error

Comment: Simply run `cd .\Downloads` and then `pkg install symbolic-2.7.1.tar.gz`!

Comment: Does cd and `untar ("symbolic-2.7.1.tar.gz")` work? I guess you have a binary `tar` in you path which isn't the "real" tar....

Comment: Yes, it does work.

Comment: I'm also having the same issue. Not able to install any package.