# Error installing package in Octave Portable on Windows 10

Tags: cygwin, octave, tar, octave-gui

I am using Octave 8.40, Portable version (the one which comes on a zip file), on Windows 10. I get the following error when trying to install a package (be it from the github or local packages):

```
>> pkg install arduino-0.12.1.tar.gz
error: unpack: unarchiving program exited with status: 2
tar: /C/PortableApps/PortableApps/octave-8.4.0-w64/arduino-0.12.1.tar.gz: Cannot open: No such file or directory
tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now
error: called from
    unpack at line 287 column 5
    untar at line 48 column 5
    install at line 99 column 9
    pkg at line 619 column 9
```

Using the command `pkg install -forge` also does not work.

(Edit) [Here is a screenshot of the Octave GUI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3SCoS.png), so it is possible to see what is the current Octave path, and the package file there. (End of edit)

I tried to add some debugging to the "unpack.m" file. There, I can see the the command issued by Octave to try to uncompress the .tar.gz file:

```
>> pkg install arduino-0.12.1.tar.gz
Current path: C:\Users\Legion\AppData\Local\Temp\oct-VvVNU6
Command is: tar xf "/C/PortableApps/PortableApps/octave-8.4.0-w64/arduino-0.12.1.tar.gz" 2>&1
error: unpack: unarchiving program exited with status: 2
tar: /C/PortableApps/PortableApps/octave-8.4.0-w64/arduino-0.12.1.tar.gz: Cannot open: No such file or directory
tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now
error: called from
    unpack at line 290 column 5
    untar at line 48 column 5
    install at line 99 column 9
    pkg at line 619 column 9
```

I tried substituting the /C/ by C:/ but then the following error shows up:

```
>> pkg install arduino-0.12.1.tar.gz
Current path: C:\Users\Legion\AppData\Local\Temp\oct-fCIzKT
Command is: tar xf "C:/PortableApps/PortableApps/octave-8.4.0-w64/arduino-0.12.1.tar.gz" 2>&1
error: unpack: unarchiving program exited with status: 128
tar: Cannot connect to C: resolve failed
error: called from
    unpack at line 290 column 5
    untar at line 48 column 5
    install at line 99 column 9
    pkg at line 619 column 9
```

Very interestingly though, if I copy the command `tar xf "C:/PortableApps/PortableApps/octave-8.4.0-w64/arduino-0.12.1.tar.gz` and use it on the cmd, it works right away. I know, the tar on the cmd is not the same tar used by Octave (which is provided by Cygwin).

(Edit 2) Following @Nick J suggestion, I tried to set Octave's env folder to somewhere above the user folder, but still had no success.

```
>> setenv('tmpdir','C:\octave\temp')
>> pkg install arduino-0.12.1.tar.gz
Current path: C:\octave\temp\oct-rF0VdY
Command is: tar xf "/C/PortableApps/PortableApps/octave-8.4.0-w64/arduino-0.12.1.tar.gz" 2>&1
error: unpack: unarchiving program exited with status: 2
tar: /C/PortableApps/PortableApps/octave-8.4.0-w64/arduino-0.12.1.tar.gz: Cannot open: No such file or directory
tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now
error: called from
    unpack at line 290 column 5
    untar at line 48 column 5
    install at line 99 column 9
    pkg at line 619 column 9
```

Even if I try using the pkg install from Github, it fails the same way:

```
>> setenv('tmpdir','C:\octave\temp')
>> pkg install "https://github.com/gnu-octave/octave-arduino/releases/download/release-0.12.1/arduino-0.12.1.tar.gz"
Current path: C:\octave\temp\oct-OnnVD1
Command is: tar xf "/C/octave/temp/oct-CxgHf3/arduino-0.12.1.tar.gz" 2>&1
error: unpack: unarchiving program exited with status: 2
tar: /C/octave/temp/oct-CxgHf3/arduino-0.12.1.tar.gz: Cannot open: No such file or directory
tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now
error: called from
    unpack at line 290 column 5
    untar at line 48 column 5
    install at line 99 column 9
    pkg at line 619 column 9
```

(End of Edit 2)

In any case, any ideas?

There is a [similar issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68209836/how-to-solve-error-installing-io-package-in-octave) but there, the problem was a non-unicode character in the path, something that is not present here. And [here,](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56307884/octave-error-installing-package-on-windows) there is no conclusion, one of the suggestions is to install the package directly from the .tar.gz, which I tried, but did not succeed.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: is the arduino-0.12.1.tar.gz in the same directory that octave has as current ? Have you played with the cygdrive definition ?

Comment: i wouldn't generally get in the habit of calling the Octave zip/7z packages "Portable" versions.  that usually has other implications, such that they don't impact the host system, leave files behind, etc., and this isn't the case.  the developers did talk about what it would take to create a truly portable version, but they haven't actually done so.

Comment: windows is notorious for having highly variable system and user folder permissions.  most package issues i've seen relate to temp folder restrictions. can you try changing octave's temp folder to something outside the user profile, perhaps a C:\octave\temp or similar? `setenv('tmpdir','C:\octave\temp')` and see if there is any change in behavior of the `pkg` command.

Comment: @matzeri Yes, the arduino package is in the current folder of Octave  `C:/PortableApps/PortableApps/octave-8.4.0-w64/` (just to make sure I will attach a picture of the Octave GUI to the post ASAP). However I didn't try to change the Cygdrive definition, I will look into that, thank you for the tip.

Comment: @NickJ Firstly thank you very much for the tip, I was not aware of that, I thought it was related to not requiring an installation. I will try to change the temp and then add the results to the main post (I am not by my laptop rn)

Comment: an interesting note, if I navigate to the folder where the packages are and try `tar xf arduino-0.12.1.tar.gz`  from Octave's command window, it will fail with same error Cannot open, starting with /C/ (so not even relative paths are working in this case)

Comment: a number of people have had strange security system related issues on their computers.  are you sysadmin on your system or is it managed?  What antivirus/antimalware/etc software is running?   are you able to try using the exe installer and seeing if you get similar results?

Comment: Hi @Nick J! So, I am the admin. I run just the usual Windows defender (normally other antivirus more annoy than really help). I am thinking about installing it to  see if the issue persist. The idea however would be having Octavr not installed so it is easy to move to other machines (almost all the other software I run is portable/portable-ish)